# Mongoose is saving documents even if I check to see if the document already exists

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I cam trying to check to see if an author is in mongo before I save the author. When I run my first rss document through the create author function, all of the authors are saved in the DB - even if they have authored two items in the feed.

What's strange is that if I run the feed through again, mongoose seems to be aware that the authors already exists and does not add them again. Can someone please explain to me what is happening?

```
function insertFeedItems(feedItems, newFeedID, callback) {
    feedItems.forEach((item) => {
        let firstName = item.author.substr(0, item.author.indexOf(' '));
        let lastName = item.author.substr(item.author.indexOf(' ') + 1);
        authorController.createAuthorInternally(firstName, lastName, function(author) {
            let aid = author.id;
            categoryController.createCategoryInternally(item.categories, function(categories) {
                // console.log('author: '+aid);
                // console.log('categories: '+categories);
            });
        });
    });

}


exports.createAuthorInternally = (firstName, lastName, callback) => {

    let author = authorFilter.validateAuthor(firstName, lastName);

    let queryParams = {
        $and: [{firstName: {$regex: firstName, $options: 'i'}},
            {lastName: {$regex: lastName, $options: 'i'}}],
    };

    let query = Author.findOne(queryParams).sort([['lastName', 'ascending']]);
    let findAuthor = query.exec();

    findAuthor.then((foundAuthor)=> {
        if (foundAuthor === null) {
            f1();
        }
    });

    function saveGuy() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            let insertNewAuthor = author.save();
            resolve(insertNewAuthor);
        });
    }

    async function f1() {
        var name = await saveGuy();
    }
};
```

Edit: I've tried this a different way:

```
 Author.count(({'firstName': firstName}, { 'lastName': lastName }), function (err,count) {
        console.log(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + count);
                if(count === 0){
                    f1();
                }
    });

function saveGuy() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let insertNewAuthor = author.save();
        resolve(insertNewAuthor);
    });
}

async function f1() {
    var name = await saveGuy();
}
```

On the first run of this new method the output is:

```
Jon Brodkin 0
Peter Bright 0
Timothy B. Lee 0
Samuel Axon 0
Kyle Orland 0
Jon Brodkin 0
Kyle Orland 0
Megan Geuss 0
Cyrus Farivar 0
Peter Bright 0
Jim Resnick 0
Cyrus Farivar 0
Kyle Orland 0
Beth Mole 0
Ars Staff 0
Megan Geuss 0
Cyrus Farivar 0
John Timmer 0
Kyle Orland 0
Samuel Axon 0
```

On the second run with the same rss feed:

```
Cyrus Farivar 3
Jon Brodkin 2
Kyle Orland 4
Megan Geuss 2
Jon Brodkin 2
Ars Staff 1
Peter Bright 2
Jim Resnick 1
Peter Bright 2
Kyle Orland 4
Megan Geuss 2
Cyrus Farivar 3
Timothy B. Lee 1
Samuel Axon 2
Kyle Orland 4
Beth Mole 1
Cyrus Farivar 3
John Timmer 1
Kyle Orland 4
Samuel Axon 2
```

As of offering the bounty, this is the method that I'm using to find and save:

```
exports.createAuthorInternally = (firstName, lastName, callback) => {

   let query = Author.findOne({firstName: firstName,lastName: lastName});

    query.exec(function(err,doc) {
        if(err){console.log(err)}
        if(!doc){
            let auth = new Author({firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName});
            auth.save(auth, function(err,newdoc) {
                if(err){console.log(err)}
                callback(newdoc);
            });
        }else{
            callback(doc);
        }

    });
```

The results are the same as in the previous methods.

Edit:
JohnnyHK pointed out my error. I've adjusted the code to reflect his answer:

```
function insertFeedItems(feedItems,newFeedID){

    async.eachSeries(feedItems, function(item, eachCallBack) {

        let firstName = item.author.substr(0, item.author.indexOf(' '));
        let lastName = item.author.substr(item.author.indexOf(' ') + 1);
        async.waterfall([
                (callback) => {
                    authorController.createAuthorInternally(firstName, lastName, function(author) {
                        return callback(null, author, item.categories);
                    });
                },
                (author, categories, callback) => {
                    categoryController.createCategoryInternally(categories, function(categories) {
                        return callback(null, author, categories);
                    });
                },
                (author, categories, callback) => {
                    feedEntryController.createFeedEntry(item, author, categories, function(entry) {
                        return callback(null, author, categories, entry);
                    });
                },
            ],
            function(waterfallError) {
                if(!waterfallError){
                    eachCallBack();
                }
            });
    }, function(eachSeriesErr) {
        if(eachSeriesErr) {
            console.log('An item failed to process');
        } else {
            console.log('All items have been processed successfully');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you sorting on a `.findOne()` call?

Comment: That's dead code. I'll remove it now. Thanks.

Comment: That didn't get rid of the double documents but, good to remove it anyway.

Comment: well it should be clear that `foundAuthor` _must_ be null. You're query is suspect (probably jacked).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It does return null for each author during the first intake of the feed. Then, it saves them - with some authors showing twice. If I intake the feed again, the query seems to work because the authors are not pulled in again.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log("name")` after the assignment inside the `f1()` function?

Comment: I get the documents that are stored in mongo. The author names are doubled up in some cases.

Comment: Last thing I have: try changing the if statement for foundAuthor. Rather than `=== null`, try the more traditional approach: `(!foundAuthor.length)` or you could test for equivalence of the actual first and/or last names rather than null.

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: thats all I can do with code fragments and no working samples. Good luck.

Comment: try with `foundAuthor ==undefined`

Comment: Thanks,  Şükran. That did not work.

Comment: you must use your code or i write a code?

Comment: There's no requirement for me to use my own code. This is a personal project. Any examples you have would would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not a full answer, but the problem is that your `feedItems.forEach` call is synchronous, but the Mongoose query operations are all async, so all your `findOne` queries have likely finished by the time you successfully save your first author (which is why all the authors appear to be new).

Comment: @JohnnyHK, thanks for pointing that out. It's working now. I've got it working by using the eachSeries function from async. I'll put the new code in the original post.

Comment: Great. If it's all working now you can add your own answer and accept it.

Comment: How would you accomplish the same thing as above except with native es7 Async/Await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JohnnyHK pointed out my error. Using the library, Async - I've adjusted the code to reflect his answer:

```
function insertFeedItems(feedItems,newFeedID){

async.eachSeries(feedItems, function(item, eachCallBack) {

    let firstName = item.author.substr(0, item.author.indexOf(' '));
    let lastName = item.author.substr(item.author.indexOf(' ') + 1);
    async.waterfall([
            (callback) => {
                authorController.createAuthorInternally(firstName, lastName, function(author) {
                    return callback(null, author, item.categories);
                });
            },
            (author, categories, callback) => {
                categoryController.createCategoryInternally(categories, function(categories) {
                    return callback(null, author, categories);
                });
            },
            (author, categories, callback) => {
                feedEntryController.createFeedEntry(item, author, categories, function(entry) {
                    return callback(null, author, categories, entry);
                });
            },
        ],
        function(waterfallError) {
            if(!waterfallError){
                eachCallBack();
            }
        });
}, function(eachSeriesErr) {
    if(eachSeriesErr) {
        console.log('An item failed to process');
    } else {
        console.log('All items have been processed successfully');
    }
});
}
```