# Mongoose/Mongodb database call returns data in an inconsistent order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am querying two different collections. The first one contains the majority of the data that I am looking for including an _id that links to the second collection. Using this _id, I want to search the second collection for the correct document and grab the Name value.

The issue I am having is 2 fold (1 is far more important than the other).

1 - When the page that makes the call first loads, it works great. If I refresh the page, and on all subsequent refreshes, it will fail. When I log the element and the index the second time, I will get the correct object but the indices will be reversed (1, 0 instead of 0, 1) and nothing will send back from the api call. I want to know why this is happening and any ways to solve it.

2 - This is a much smaller issue. If I change `allStudents[i].Teacher = teacherData.Name;` which replaces the value an existing field then it works just fine. But, if I change it to `allStudents[i].TeacherName = teacherData.Name;` which is adding a new field to the object then it will add nothing at all. I do not understand why I am unable to added a new field to an object even though I have never had issues with this before?

```
export const getAllStudents = (req, res) => {
  Student.find(
    { UserType: "STUDENT" },
    req.query.fields    
  )
  .then(data => {
    console.log('line 34')
    if (data) {
      let allStudents = [];
      data.forEach((e, i) => {
        console.log('line 38', e.Teacher);
        Teacher.findOne(
          { _id: e.Teacher },
          'Name'
        )
        .then(teacherData => {
          console.log('line 44', e, i === data.length - 1)
          allStudents.push(e);
          if (studentData && i !== data.length - 1) {
            allStudents[i].Teacher = teacherData.Name;
          } else if (partnerData) {
            allStudents[i].Teacher = teacherData.Name;
            console.log('line 50')
            res.json({ data: allStudents }).status(200);
          } else res.json({ message: "No Teacher is associated with this user." }).status(401);
        })
        .catch(err => res.json({ message: "No Teacher is associated with this user." }).status(401));
      })
    } else res.json({ message: "No student could be found." }).status(401);
  })
  .catch(err => res.json({ message: "No student could be found." }).status(401));
}
```

The console.log output is as follows:

```
[0] line 44 { _id: 5ab94d69418a5132507d5b41,
[0]   FirstName: 'PersonA',
[0]   LastName: 'Lastname',
[0]   Email: 's@example.ca',
[0]   Teacher: '5ab94d69418a5132507d5b60' } 0 false
[0] line 44 { _id: 5ab94d69418a5132507d5b42,
[0]   FirstName: 'PersonB',
[0]   LastName: 'Lastname',
[0]   Email: 'student@example.com',
[0]   Teacher: '5ab94d69418a5132507d5b60' } 2 true
[0] line 44 { _id: 5ab94d69418a5132507d5b39,
[0]   FirstName: 'PersonC',
[0]   LastName: 'Lastname',
[0]   Email: 'a@exmple.ca',
[0]   Teacher: '5ab94d69418a5132507d5b59' } 1 false
```

Comment: Same basic issue of `forEach` being synchronous while Mongoose operations are async as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639236/mongoose-is-saving-documents-even-if-i-check-to-see-if-the-document-already-exis

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by created two basic api calls, then organized the data in my Redux Action.